# why does my wordpress instance return page with strange string?

Tags: wordpress

I have an running wordpress, it runs well on my localhost. After I deploy it to production, it still runs well, but returns page with strange string on top of the page. http://api.libwy.com. The message shows that it has something to do with Mac Os X attr 'com.apple.quarantineq/0003'. Anybody knows why I get this and what com.apple.quarantineq is doing here?

Answer (score 1):

The  attribute is added so that it can ask for user confirmation the first time the downloaded program is run, to help stop malware. Upon confirmation the attribute should be removed and then the program will run normally.

Since we have no information about the webserver you use, i would assume the issue is with it (is it a Mac server?). You need to find some way to "confirm" this message once on the server and it will permanently get rid of it.

Comment: so kind of you replying and helping. I am using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20+ngix-1.4.6